# Excluding first cell in HTMLTableRowElement

Tags: javascript

I am kind of new to javascript and trying to accomplish a simple (yet complicated for me) task. I am trying to exclude first row and first column from a table and got stuck in excluding first cell in every row from this table (HTMLTableRowElement). Following is my sample code.

```
function clickSchedule(){
    var table
    var grow   // group row 
    table= document.getElementById("myTable");
    grow = table.rows;
    for(var i= 1; i<= grow.length ; i++ ){
         var cellIndex = this.cells; 
          for( var j =1 ; j<= cellIndex.length ; j++ ){
               this.onclick = function () {
               alert("test");
               }
         }
    }
```

The first "for loop" will grab all rows from the table excluding row[0] that is why you can see var i = 1. Next, I am storing cells from all rows to a variable and trying to exclude cell[0] using second "for loop" in order to perform an onclick event to the selected table area.

Also, is it possible to get the index value of the selected cell from this table?

I would really appreciated your help

Faraz Amjad

Comment: you already did everything ?

Comment: What is `this.cells` in your code? Is it `grow[i].cells`? And what do you mean by `this.onclick`, while `this` looks like pointing to `window`?

Comment: Yes Mohamed, with the above sample, I could be able to exclude first row and just first column which can be done excluding first cell but I dont know how?

Comment: Yes Leo, it is grow[i].cells. and "this" is cellIndex[j].onclick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your logical part is right and wrong.

   - Start iteration from index `1` is right.
   - `i <= grow.length` means when it's true, go on iteration. But when `i == grow.length`, `grow[i]` should be `undefined`, because `grow.length-1` is the last index. So the right condition expression should be `i < grow.length`.
2. You didn't do event binding right in iterations.

   Try this one:

```js
(function(){
  var table = document.querySelector('table')
  var rows = table.rows
  var cells

  for(var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++ ) {
    cells = rows[i].cells
    for(var j = 1; j < cells.length; j++ ) {
      cells[j].onclick = function() {
        alert(this.innerHTML);
      }
    }
  }
})()
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a1</td><td>a2</td><td>a3</td><td>a4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b1</td><td>b2</td><td>b3</td><td>b4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c1</td><td>c2</td><td>c3</td><td>c4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>d1</td><td>d2</td><td>d3</td><td>d4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a million Leo, this works perfectly. Just one more thing how can we get the value of j meaning that onclick value of iteration? Thanks buddy!!

Comment: @Faraz_pk are you saying you want to `alert(j)` when cell clicked?

Comment: alert(j) returns undefined. However, I found the answer

it is alert(this.cellIndex)  // because alert(this) returns HTMLTableCellElement and cellIndex is its property